# Quality Undergraduate Physics Resources in French

Tags: resource-recommendations, foundations

Context: I am embarking on my journey into physics as a beginner. Four years ago, I completed my Baccalaureate (high school diploma) and subsequently pursued software engineering independently. It's only now, four years later, that I am beginning to appreciate the beauty of physics and science in general. I've had to reevaluate and unlearn some of the teachings from high school, as they were not properly conveyed.

Now that I am committed to studying physics rigorously, I am seeking comprehensive resources in French (as I am from a Francophone African country). I am essentially starting from scratch and need materials that provide detailed explanations.

P.S: I possess the necessary mathematical foundation to tackle undergraduate physics.

Please if you know someone who studied physics in French, do not hesitate to share this question with him. Thanks

Comment: Bienvenue au Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a French physics student, there is a nice serie of books by Pérez covering most of the undergraduate (licence) level : mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics etc. But he uses a lot of maths without always diving into the physical meaning.

The Feynman's lectures are great !! and are translated in French. They represent an other approach, more based on physics.

Comment: Les livres au Feynman sont excellent, mais utilise le calcul differentielle et integrelle.

Comment: Bien sûr, on ne fait pas de physique sans maths ;)

Comment: T'as de raison!